# How do I list files and directories those are not hidden in current directory using crystal language?

Tags: crystal-lang

I wrote my own minimal version of "ls" command (Linux) using crystal language and here is my code:

```
require "dir"
require "file"

def main()

    pwd = Dir.current
    list_dir = Dir.children(pwd)
    
    puts("[+] location: #{pwd}")
    puts("------------------------------------------")
    
    list_dir.each do |line|

        check = File.file?(line)

        if check == true
            puts("[+] file     : #{line}")
        elsif check == false
            puts("[+] directory: #{line}")
        else 
            puts("[+] unknown  : #{line}")
        end
    end
end

main
```

It works but it also listing all hidden files and directories (.files & .directories) too and I do not want to show those. I want the result more like "ls -l" command's result not like "ls -la".
So, what I need to implement to stop showing hidden files and directories?

Comment: Yes that's what you need to implement. As you already noticed hidden files and directories always start with a `.` dot in their name and non-hidden files and directories never do so.

Comment: Yes, I understand the logic but I had no idea how to implement that. So I added: " line 9: if line[0] == '.' " and "line 10: else " (after: list_dir.each do |line|) and (before: check = File.file?(line)). Now it is working as I expected but is it a good practice to keep a if statement empty. I mean of course it contains conditional but conditional only, no codes.

Comment: Another note on your code: `if check == true` is extra verbose. `if check` would work as well. `elsif check == false` is unnecessary, because `check` is of type `Bool`, so if it's not `true`, it can only be `false`. Thus the third branch (about "unknown") can never be reached. So your code has a bug that everything that is not a file would be labeled as a directory.
A better approach to identifying the type would be `File.info(line).type` (see [`File.info`](https://crystal-lang.org/api/1.5.0/File.html#info%28path%3APath%7CString%2Cfollow_symlinks%3Dtrue%29%3AInfo-class-method)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing special about "hidden" files. It's just a convention to hide file names starting with a dot in some contexts by default. `Dir.children` does not follow that convention and expects the user to apply approriate filtering.

The recommended way to check if a file name starts with a dot is `file_name.starts_with?(".")`.